# Easier + Optimum way of doing binary division

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, binary

Can anyone suggest what is the most straightforward + optimum way of doing binary division **without using recursion** in Java?

I have the following code which even though works fine but I believe this basic Maths function should be much more easier here.

```
private static int div(int dividend, int divisor) {
    int denom = divisor;
    int count = 1;
    while (denom <= dividend) {
        denom <<= 1;
        count <<= 1;
    }
    if (denom > dividend) {
        denom >>= 1; count >>= 1;
    }

    int answer = 0;
    // Now find the smaller dividend
    while (count != 0) {
        if (dividend >= denom) {
            dividend = dividend - denom;
            // Consume the count value;
            answer = answer + count;
        }
        count >>>= 1;
        denom >>= 1;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: This is not a recursive function, it is an iterative one. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: This code works. Why do you think it should be *easier*, and what does *easier* even mean?

Comment: Less lines of code maybe. "Easier to type"

Comment: @piokuc - I know this is not recursive, but I am looking for the solution which is non-recursive + easier then above. Somehow it is hard to believe there is no bitwiddler which can solve this in couple of lines.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName - Looking for radically different approach with far less number of lines then used in above code.
@ CloseVoters - please care to explain for requesting to close? I am seriously looking for easier solution here.

Comment: You are doing it the hard way b doing it manually instead of doing `/` so it is hard to suggest how to do the easier-hard way.

Comment: much simpler: return dividend / divisor;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that division is kind of a difficult algorithm to implement.

The algorithm you outline above is produces one bit per iteration and (as dividers go) it's fairly simple.

There are other algorithms that also produce 1 bit per iteration (e.g., CORDIC and binary restoring). None of them is a one or two liner, but you *might* find one of them a little simpler and more understandable.

There are other divider algorithms that can produce more bits per iteration. For example, an SRT radix-4 divider can produce 4 bits per iteration. The expense is that the algorithm is even *more* complex. If you're having difficulty with the algorithm you gave, my immediate guess is that you'd find these somewhere between hideous and utterly hopeless.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct; there is a one-liner for this:

```
private static int div(int dividend, int divisor) {
  return dividend / divisor;
}
```

Comment: I am looking not to use division operator, but I am giving you +1 for pun!